# Converting TimeStamp to HH:MM:SS format

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datetime, timespan

Hi i'm working on Oracle stored procedure in which i'm subtracting two dates and is returning Timespan like +00 hh:mm:ss.ff format now i want to access only HH:MM:SS format either in the stored proc or in asp.net application. When i try to return timespan as it is that is the result which i get after subtraction i cannot find a way to read it as it is not Date time. I want to disply time span in HH:MM:SS format either from data base side or from front end side. I tried using following methods.

```
 1)TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(((MAX(COMPLETED_DATE)-MAX(REQUEST_DATE))*24),'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

so that later i can extract hh:mm:ss from this later but this is throwing error

```
 2)  TO_CHAR(((MAX(S.COMPLETED_DATE)-MAX(S.REQUEST_DATE))*24))
```

It is returning time in +00 hh:mm:ss.ff format and i can't extract hh:MM:SS from this

Answer (score 1):

The difference of two dates is not a `DateTime`, but rather a `TimeSpan`.  You shouldn't need to use strings to convey that.

You *should* be able to return:

```
MAX(S.COMPLETED_DATE)-MAX(S.REQUEST_DATE)
```

The result should go in a `TimeSpan` type in C#.  Then you can use a [custom TimeSpan format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for output in whatever format you desire.

If for some reason that doesn't work, consider returning the two dates separately from Oracle, then subtract them in your C# code.